# Angular: check if Observable / BehaviorSubject has relevant changes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a user object which I observe in a membership service.

I want to update my services only if the user object has relevant changes.

To understand if my user object has relevant changes, I compare my local user object with the observed one. And always assign the new object afterwards.

This does not work, however.

```js
export class MemberService {
  private subscription?: Subscription;
  user?: User;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    this.subscription = this.auth.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      const updateServices = this.hasUserRelevantChanges(user)

      // apparently this line always fires before the functioncall above?!
      this.user = user;

      if (updateServices) {
         this.updateMyServices();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }

  hasUserRelevantChanges(user: User | undefined): boolean {
      return user?.subscription !== this.user?.subscription ||
          user?.username !== this.user?.username ||
          user?.isBanned !== this.user?.isBanned;
  }

  updateMyServices(): void {
    // Updating my services!!!
  }
}

export class AuthService {
  public readonly user$: Observable<User| undefined> = this.user.asObservable();
  user: BehaviorSubject<User| undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<User| undefined>(undefined);

    constructor(private httpHandler: HttpHandlerService) { ... }

  handleUser(): void {
    this.httpHandler.login().subscribe(
        (user: User) => this.user.next(user));
  }

  updateUserData(newUser: User): void {
    this.user.next(Object.assign(this.user.value, newUser));
  }
}
```

How come that my function `hasUserRelevantChanges()` always compares the same, new objects? The local `this.user` always holds the new values already within this check, eventhough the assignment `this.user = user` comes afterwards?

So how can I understand if my new `user` object has the relevant values changed in comparison to the old/previous user-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"How come that my function `hasUserRelevantChanges()` always compares the same, new objects?"*

That's because you're always assigning the new values to the `this.user` variable. Ideally you'd need to update it with the new `user` *only* if it's different. In other words, it must be moved inside the `if` block.

```js
this.subscription = this.auth.user$.subscribe((user) => {
  const updateServices = this.hasUserRelevantChanges(user)

  if (updateServices) {
    this.user = user;
    this.updateMyServices();
  }
});
```

#### Update: [`pairwise`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) + [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter)

In your scenario, you would do better to use the RxJS `pairwise` + `filter` operators to check the condition.

```js
this.subscription = this.auth.user$.pipe(
  pairwise(),
  filter(([user1, user2]) => (
    user1?.subscription !== user2?.subscription ||
    user1?.username !== user2?.username ||
    user1?.isBanned !== user2?.isBanned;
  ))
).subscribe(([user1, user2]) => {    // <-- Update 2: ignore `user1`
  this.updateMyServices(user2);
);
```

If you're actually comparing all the properties of the object with it's previous values, you could replace the entire `pairwise` + `filter` with the [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged) operator.

Comment: But I make the `hasUserRelevantChanges(user)` call BEFORE the assignment is done, how come the function acts like if the assignment was done already?:/

Comment: @TeaCup: I'm not exactly sure what do you mean by the assignment is done already. What makes you believe so? On the other hand, I've updated the answer using RxJS operators `pairwise` + `filter` that IMO is better suited to your requirement.

Comment: I have made the changes as proposed and now use pairwise filter, but I still receive twice the same object every time I make changes;(

Comment: @TeaCup: Indeed, using `pairwise` would emit two values, previous and current. As shown in `filter(([user1, user2]) => ()` statement you could get both users in the subscription callback and ignore the `user1` which is the previous value. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RxJs` operators to do so. You don't need to store user somewhere in your code but you can `pipe` it with `pairwise` and `filter`. So it would be something like this:

```
this.auth.user$.pipe(
           pairwise(), 
           filter(users => userChanged(users[0], users[1]))
           ... // other operators to handle change - tap, map etc
           )
```

It will be much cleaner if you move logic to proper operators.

Edit: `Pairwise` returns two values: previous and current, `filter` - as the name says filter events and emits next only if passed callback returns true

Edit2: You should implement `userChanged` or adjust your `hasUserRelevantChanges` which now you would need to pass 2 arguments.

Edit3: Why your code doesn't work? Because `Object.assign` doesn't create new object reference but change original object - so in fact, you are checking everytime the same object.

Update: Spread operator:

```
updateUserData(newUser: User): void {
this.user.next({...this.user.value, ...newUser});
```

}

Comment: Object shallow copy is a good point. If OP wishes to ignore the RxJS operators, they could try to make a rudimentary [deep object copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/6513921).

Comment: I tried to use pairwise filter but unfortunately the filter comparison would also just compare the same objects all the time, it does not store the value of the old object;(

Comment: Just remove `Object.assign` and use spread operator. It will create new object with updated values. I will edit my answer.